# Can't install centos-gluster9

Tags: centos7, glusterfs

I'm trying to install glusterfs on my centos 7 server, I already install centos-release-gluster

```
[root@core11 media]# yum install centos-release-gluster
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.labkom.id
 * centos-gluster9: vpsmurah.jagoanhosting.com
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * extras: vpsmurah.jagoanhosting.com
 * updates: vpsmurah.jagoanhosting.com
211 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package centos-release-gluster9-1.0-1.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

but when I continue to install glusterfs-server, it has error

```
[root@core11 media]# yum install glusterfs-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.labkom.id
 * centos-gluster9: vpsmurah.jagoanhosting.com
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * extras: vpsmurah.jagoanhosting.com
 * updates: vpsmurah.jagoanhosting.com
211 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glusterfs-server.x86_64 0:9.3-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glusterfs = 9.3-1.el7 for package: glusterfs-server-9.3-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glusterfs-cli = 9.3-1.el7 for package: glusterfs-server-9.3-1.el7.x86_6
--> Processing Dependency: liburcu-bp.so.6()(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-9.3-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liburcu-cds.so.6()(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-9.3-1.el7.x86_64
...
Error: Package: libgfrpc0-9.3-1.el7.x86_64 (centos-gluster9)
       Requires: liburcu-bp.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: glusterfs-9.3-1.el7.x86_64 (centos-gluster9)
       Requires: liburcu-cds.so.6()(64bit)
...
```

Is there a step that I missed?

Comment: ? May be you are missing `yum install centos-release-gluster9` ? ..... The package providing 'liburcu-*' is **userspace-rcu** http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.9.2009/storage/x86_64/gluster-9/Packages/u/ .... Ref. storage http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.9.2009/storage/x86_64/gluster-9/Packages/

Comment: Thank you! it successfully installed after installing userspace-rcu by 

yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.9.2009/storage/x86_64/gluster-9/Packages/u/userspace-rcu-0.10.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to install **userpace-rcu** as Knud mentioned above, since I'm using Centos 7 with x86_64 architecture, I just need to install this package before installing glusterfs-server

yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.9.2009/storage/x86_64/gluster-9/Packages/u/userspace-rcu-0.10.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 0):

On `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)` I install (`glusterfs-server`) as shown as :

```
yum install dnf -y
dnf -y install centos-release-gluster8
yum install -y  glusterfs-server
```

Note: If you get  `Connection refused` error, You must try again enter command. Because your internet connection is lost.